# Can't make Metricbeat use passed env variable

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I'm trying to run `metricbeat` service in docker, according to the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/running-on-docker.html) (version 7.2.0). Here's my bash command for `setup`:

```sh
docker run -d --name=metricbeat docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:7.2.0 setup\
 -e setup.kibana.host=http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5601\
 -e output.elasticsearch.host=["XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"]\
 -e output.elasticsearch.password=XXXXXXXX
```

As you see I'm passing the `output.elasticsearch.host` variable and it's definitely not equal to the default value. But here's the part of the `metricbeat` container logs:

```sh
2019-07-31T14:32:40.335Z        INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:166     Elasticsearch url: http://elasticsearch:9200
```

This means that `metricbeat` used the default Elastic host instead of the environment variable value. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a typo, there is a `s` missing in `output.elasticsearch.hosts`.

Use also double quotes around the whole environment variable definition and single quotes around the host value, such as:

```
-E "output.elasticsearch.hosts=['http://myhost:9200']"
```

The above example is directly taken from the official documentation about [global flags](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/7.2/command-line-options.html#global-flags).